# Fundamental group of the quotient of a torus

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

Which is the fundamental group of the following space: $S^1 \times S^1/\cong$ where $\cong$ is the equivalence relation identifying two distinct points $p$ and $q$?

First of all, in the comments I ask what happens when at least one of the points, say $P$, stays in the boundary. It has been answered me that it doesn't matter, since I can construct a homeomorphism to another torus in which these points both belong to the interior of the square. I want to know why the homeomorphism does not create problems with the fact that $P$ identifies with some $P'$ in the other side.

I want to use Van Kampen theorem and I draw a picture of the square with the edges labelled by $a,b,a^{-1}$ and $b^{-1}$. I suppose firstly that the two points are in the interior of the square. How I have to take the two open sets needed to use Van Kampen theorem? Can you provide a detailed formal proof, answering point by point to the solution given below.

Comment: A related question, a sphere with 2 points identified,  and some answers are at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/179999/are-these-two-spaces-homotopy-equivalent

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to do it this way, I'll draw a picture for you:

[image]

We'll take $U$ to be the union of the yellow and red regions, and we'll take $V$ to be the union of the blue and red regions. So $U \cap V$ is the red region.

Now, a few sketchy hints:

- Try to convince yourself that $U$ deformation retracts on the line segment joining $p$ and $q$, which is really a circle, because $p$ and $q$ are the same point. What is the fundamental group of $U$ then? What does the generator of $\pi_1(U)$ look like on the diagram?
- Similarly, you can convince yourself that $V$ deformation retracts onto the "border" of the square, which is the same thing as your $a$ and $b$ circles joined at the "corner-point". So what is $\pi_1(V)$? And what do its generators look like on the diagram?
- $U \cap V$ is an annulus, so its fundamental group is $\mathbb Z$. You should try to identity the image of generator of $\pi_1(U \cap V)$ under the maps $$(i_1)_\star : \pi_1(U \cap V) \to \pi_1(U), \ \ \ \ \ \ (i_2)_\star : \pi_1(U \cap V) \to \pi_1(V),$$
  where $i_1 : U \cap V \hookrightarrow U$ and $i_2 : U \cap V \hookrightarrow V$ are the natural inclusions.
- Finally, apply Seifert-van Kampen.

Feel free to ask more questions if these hints are too cryptic.

---

By the way, a simpler way to visualise this is to convince yourself that the torus with $p$ and $q$ identified is homotopy equivalent to the torus plus a line segment glued at its endpoints to $p$ and $q$. This is then homotopy equivalent to a torus plus a circle glued at a single point:

[image]

Comment: thank you! What happens when $P$ and $Q$ both belong to the boundary? And if one of them stays in the boundary, while the other in the interior?

Comment: @TheWanderer Putting $P$ and/or $Q$ on the boundary makes no difference. You can just "shift" the "border" of the square. Said another way, you can find a homeomorphism from the torus to itself so that, after performing the homeomorphism, $P$ and $Q$ are no longer on the boundary.

Comment: Is there an explicit way to write down the homeomorphism you are talking about?

Comment: @TheWanderer For example if the square is $[0,1] \times [0,1]$, and if $P = (0, 0.3)$ and $Q = (0.4, 0)$, then you can perform the translation $(x,y) \mapsto (x + 0.1, y + 0.1)$. Then $P$ becomes $(0.1,0.4)$ and $Q$ becomes $(0.5,0.1)$, and your points are no longer on the "border".

Comment: And is it possible although the natural identifications defining the torus?

Answer (score 0):

It’s a quite easy question. Consider the homotopy type of it, use a curve outside the torus to connect the two points, the use a curve inside the torus to contract the two points to one point. Then the space is homotopic to T^2 wedge sum with S^1